# Join two table with inner join and two external keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table:

Table Utenti:

[image: Table Utenti]

Table Social:

[image: Table Social]

I want this result:

```
Federica - Luca 0.1
Federica - Vincenzo 0.6
Federica - Silvia 0.3
...
Silvia - Vincenzo 0.5
```

How do I do the inner join between the two table recovering both the Username?

I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Utenti 
INNER  JOIN Social 
         ON Utenti.ID_UT = Social.ID_UT1 
           AND Utenti.ID_UT = Social.ID_UT2
```

Comment: FYI - table, plus example data, plus expected results, plus what you have tried...perfect way to ask a question, I'd +4 upvote it if I could.  Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close...use social as your starting point and join to the Utenti table twice, once for each ID.

```
 SELECT u1.username, u2.username,social.val
 FROM social 
 INNER JOIN utenti u1 ON U1.ID_UT=Social.ID_UT1
 inner join utenti u2 ON U2.ID_UT=Social.ID_UT2
```

You can join the same table multiple times, as long as you specify an alias (the u1 and u2 here).

Comment: This works but why have I the results conversely?
`Luca Russo-Federica Savino: 0.4
Vincenzo Bruscino-Federica Savino: 0.6
Silvia Rossi-Federica Savino: 0.1
Federica Savino-Luca Russo: 0.1
Vincenzo Bruscino-Luca Russo: 0
Silvia Rossi-Luca Russo: 0.4
Federica Savino-Vincenzo Bruscino: 0.6
Luca Russo-Vincenzo Bruscino: 0.1
Silvia Rossi-Vincenzo Bruscino: 0.5
Federica Savino-Silvia Rossi: 0.3
Luca Russo-Silvia Rossi: 0.5
Vincenzo Bruscino-Silvia Rossi: 0.4`

Comment: conversely?  If you mean the column order, switch around the order in which they appear in the select clause.  I'm a little confused though, I though u1,u2 was what you wanted with the table layout

Comment: Ok, I have resolved. I have modified the select and the On clause: `SELECT u2.Nome, u1.Nome, Social.Val
                FROM Social
                INNER JOIN Utenti u1 ON u1.ID_UT=Social.ID_UT2
                INNER JOIN Utenti u2 ON u2.ID_UT=Social.ID_UT1` Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u1.Username, u2.Username, s.val
```

FROM Social s
  JOIN Utenti u1 ON u1.ID_UT = s.ID_UT1
  JOIN Utenti u2 ON u2.ID_UT = s.ID_UT2